# PHP - Generate transparency (or opacity) gradient using image

Tags: php, image, transparency, gd

Using PHP is it possible to take an existing image and produce a copy where the original image changes from 100% opaque to 0% opaque (or 0% transparent to 100% transparent!)?

Thanks,

Toby

***EDIT: I realise my question was unclear, apologies. I want to take an image and create an opacity gradient across it, so the image is 100% opaque at the top, 100% transparent at the bottom and translucent in between.***

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do but why not just hide the image with CSS and JavaScript?

Comment: do u want a gradient that varies from transparent to solid, or a image that varies from translucent to solid?

Comment: stillstanding, yes, transparent to solid- that was the 'gradient' bit, sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: well it was pretty clear, I'm currently searching for the same solution, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you change from 100% opaque to 0% opaque the image wouldn't be visible anymore. What do you want to do exactly? Change The whole Image or only a part? I would consider of using CSS (maybe + javascript) where you are able to set the transparency between 0% and 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you take an image from 100% to 0%, it disappears right ?  and 0% to 100% means it was transparent so it went black?  I'm not sure exactly what you are asking bu try [this tutorial](http://www.bitrepository.com/image-transparency-with-gd.html)

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear - I want to take an image and make an opacity gradient across it, so it's solid at the top fading to transparent at the bottom (and therefore translucent in the middle).