# php image manipulation - fade to transparency

Tags: php, image

does anyone know how to apply fade effect to an image using PHP ? what I am looking for is a way to apply gradient transparency ( i mean : at the top , the image is opaque , which gradually gets more and more transparent , and at the bottom it is completely transparent).

i have been reading up on http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php , but did not see anything about applying a gradient effect to an image.

i also read : [PHP - Generate transparency (or opacity) gradient using image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136152/php-generate-transparency-or-opacity-gradient-using-image) , but it kinda trailed off without any solution!

I am also open to any other suggestion / libraries that can do this from command line.

Comment: just fone : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727197/can-you-get-a-transparent-gradient-using-php-imagemagick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you'll need to work with a png for this effect, but you can convert any png into a jpg using php.  The following question I believe covers what you are asking about.  Part of the code will have to be removed to clear the image reflection effect.

[Can You Get a Transparent Gradient using PHP ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727197/can-you-get-a-transparent-gradient-using-php-imagemagick)

The piece of code which seems to do what you are trying to accomplish is:

```
$im = new Imagick('image.jpg'); //Reference image location

if (!$im->getImageAlphaChannel()) {
    $im->setImageAlphaChannel(Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SET);
}

$refl = $im->clone();
$refl->flipImage();

$gradient = new Imagick();

$gradient->newPseudoImage($refl->getImageWidth() + 10, $refl->getImageHeight() + 10, "gradient:transparent-black");
```